# Iterating over folder to get csv files and merge them to separate sheets in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I'm trying to write a short script that will identify all csv files in a folder structure and then will take each one and put it in a separate sheet and give them the  parent folder name.

this is what I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import os as os
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl

input_dir = r"C:\..."

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_dir):
    for file in files:
        df = []
        if file.endswith('{}'.format('csv')):
                writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out.xlsx,
                                    engine='xlsxwriter')
            sheet_name = os.path.join(root.split('\\')[6], root.split('\\')[7])
            new_name = sheet_name.replace('\\', '-')
            df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, file))
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=new_name, index=False)
            writer.save()
```

it does insert the csv's to the xlsx and give the right name but it overrides the data each time and i only get the last csv in the folder.

any suggestions?

thank you

Comment: If there are multiple csvs in the same folder, they will be given the same name (because your name is based on the parent folder) and therefore overwrite each other because sheetnames have to be unique. What do you want to happen when there are multiple csv files in the same folder?

Comment: your main issue here is that your creating the `writer` object each time essentially writing a new excel with every iteration. as @AlfredRodenboog has stated, you need to outline a rule for dealing with multiple CSVs in a single parent folder.

Comment: there are no multiple cvs's in the same folder. just 1 per folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use pathlib in conjunction with pandas.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd 

start_dir = 'C:\...'

files = Path(start_dir).rglob('*.csv') # finds all child csvs. 

#writer object outside loop. 
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r"C:\Users\Omer Davidi\Downloads\dry+breath\dry+breath\out.xlsx",
                                engine='xlsxwriter')


for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=file.parent.name,index=False)

# save object after iteration ends.
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the writer outside the loop:

```
import pandas as pd
import os as os
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl

input_dir = r"C:\..."

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out.xlsx, engine='xlsxwriter')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_dir):
    for file in files:
        df = []
        if file.endswith('{}'.format('csv')):
            sheet_name = os.path.join(root.split('\\')[6], root.split('\\')[7])
            new_name = sheet_name.replace('\\', '-')
            df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, file))
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=new_name, index=False)
            writer.save()
```